# VBA copy data from other workbook without read sheetname on that workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code to copy data from one workbook to other workbook in excel.

```
Option Explicit


Public Sub GetData(SourceFile As Variant, SourceSheet As String, _
                   SourceRange As String, TargetRange As Range, Header As Boolean, UseHeaderRow As Boolean)

    Dim rsCon As Object
    Dim rsData As Object
    Dim szConnect As String
    Dim szSQL As String
    Dim lCount As Long

    ' Create the connection string.
    If Header = False Then
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No"";"
        Else
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"";"
        End If
    Else
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";"
        Else
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"";"
        End If
    End If

    If SourceSheet = "" Then
        ' workbook level name
        szSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & SourceRange$ & ";"
    Else
        ' worksheet level name or range
        szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "];"
    End If

    On Error GoTo SomethingWrong

    Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    rsCon.Open szConnect
    rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1

    ' Check to make sure we received data and copy the data
    If Not rsData.EOF Then

        If Header = False Then
            TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
        Else
            'Add the header cell in each column if the last argument is True
            If UseHeaderRow Then
                For lCount = 0 To rsData.Fields.Count - 1
                    TargetRange.Cells(1, 1 + lCount).Value = _
                    rsData.Fields(lCount).Name
                Next lCount
                TargetRange.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
            Else
                TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
            End If
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox "No records returned from : " & SourceFile, vbCritical
    End If

    ' Clean up our Recordset object.
    rsData.Close
    Set rsData = Nothing
    rsCon.Close
    Set rsCon = Nothing
    Exit Sub

SomethingWrong:
    MsgBox "The file name, Sheet name or Range is invalid of : " & SourceFile, _
           vbExclamation, "Error"
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function


Function Array_Sort(ArrayList As Variant) As Variant
    Dim aCnt As Integer, bCnt As Integer
    Dim tempStr As String

    For aCnt = LBound(ArrayList) To UBound(ArrayList) - 1
        For bCnt = aCnt + 1 To UBound(ArrayList)
            If ArrayList(aCnt) > ArrayList(bCnt) Then
                tempStr = ArrayList(bCnt)
                ArrayList(bCnt) = ArrayList(aCnt)
                ArrayList(aCnt) = tempStr
            End If
        Next bCnt
    Next aCnt
    Array_Sort = ArrayList
End Function
```

In this code, I need to write sheet name on other workbook where i want to retrieve the data, so the code can work. it will be like this:

```
Dim IonessencePerProduct As Variant

IonessencePerProduct = "E:\Data Kantor\Amerta Indah Otsuka\
Project Sales Progress\SMRY_SI_PRODUCT_VALUE_crosstab_ionnesence.xlsx"

        GetData IonessencePerProduct, "SMRY_SI_PRODUCT_VALUE_crosstab_", "C2:O3", 
    Sheets("Summary Value Ion Essence").Range("D18:P19"), False, False
```

Is there any way to retrive data from other workbook without read sheet name. Let say just select first sheet on that workbook but i need to paste it on certain sheet in the other workbook.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: To refer to the first worksheet within the other workbook all you need to do is `Workbooks("WorkbookName").Sheets(1)`. You can use index numbers to refer to the location of the sheet without knowing its name.

Comment: how can I write it in my code above? where should I add workbooks ("workbookname").Sheets(1)

Comment: You need to change how you are passing in the workbook and worksheet argument. A quick fix would be to pass in the worksheet name as `Workbooks("WorkbookName").Worksheets(1).Name" but I would have to see how you are using the sub to really refactor it (and doing so would be more appropriate for CodeReview anyways).

Comment: I just  revise my code. That is the way I copy  data which I save the workbook in variable. Then I need to write the sheetname "SMRY_SI_PRODUCT_VALUE_crosstab_" and range.  After that I paste to other workbooks with the sheetname "Summary Value Ion Essence" and the range. I don't  wanna write sheetname "SMRY_SI_PRODUCT_VALUE_crosstab_". I want to change it to first sheet. How can I do it?

Comment: Wherever you are using "SMRY_SI_PRODUCT_VALUE_crosstab_" just reference the sheet's name instead. So for example, if this was the first sheet within the workbook running the code you could do `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name`. If it is the second sheet, do `Sheets(2)` etc.

Comment: It doesn't work if I replace sheet name with ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name. I need to write the sheet name so it can work. How can I do it with ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name?

Comment: Use `Debug.Print` to ensure that 'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name` is returning a name. I would also encourage you to play around a bit on this. Calling on the `Name` property should work just fine, but it will depend on what you are trying to do with the name returned.